# Printing out individual values from a randomly generated array

Tags: arrays, output

For this assignment, we need to ask a person to input number of people and number of years. The program then gets random numbers from an array and then gives out a bunch of different information. What I've managed to do so far is this:
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class InternSalary {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    Scanner s = new Scanner (System.in);
    Random myRandom = new Random();

    int value = myRandom.nextInt(19000) + 1000;
    int years = 0;
    int people = 0;
    int total = 0;
    int average = 0;



    System.out.println("Enter number of people for which you have salary information");
    people = s.nextInt();
    System.out.println("Enter number of years for which you have salary information");
    years = s.nextInt();



    int [][] salaries = new int [people][years];

    for (int i=0; i<people; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j <years; j++)
            salaries[i][j] = myRandom.nextInt (19000)+1000;
        }

    for (int i = 0; i < people; i++) {
        total = 0;
           for(int j = 0; j < years; j++) {
               total += salaries[i][j];

        }

           System.out.println(total/years);
           System.out.println(total);




    }
}
```

}
   This gives the average a person made per year, and then the total they made. It's still not formatted, but I'll do that later. What I can't figure out is how to output how much a person made each individual year,which are the numbers added together to get the total amount a person made. Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within this section you need to print out each salary.
If you think about it you were adding the salary for each year to the total. So why not just print it out with whatever formatting that you need.

```
for(int j = 0; j < years; j++) {
           total += salaries[i][j];
           //add this line
           System.out.println(salaries[i][j]);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It works perfectly now! I still have to format it to make it look like a table, but I'm saving that for later.